# Detect collision of two UIView's in swift

Tags: ios, collision-detection, uipangesturerecognizer

I have two UIViews on my ViewController. I added panGesture to first view and when i start moving this view the second view will move towards first view. I want to detect an event when these two views collides. Here is my code.

```
@IBAction func dragFirstView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(2.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.secondView.frame = CGRectMake(sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, sender.view!.center.y + translation.y, self.secondView.frame.size.width, self.secondView.frame.size.height)
                }, completion: nil)
        }

        sender.view!.center = CGPoint(x: sender.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: sender.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

what about

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(secondView.frame, sender.frame)) {
        // Do something
    }
```

> [CGRectIntersectsRect(*:*:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) : Returns whether two rectangles intersect.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 CGRectIntersectsRect replace with intersects

```
for collider in colliders
        {
            if (collider.frame.intersects(frameTarget)) {
                return
            }
        }
```