# ios swift - check for single view touching another views

Tags: ios, swift, math

I have 2 uiviews that will move in a certan area, and i need a method that should calls when the views touchs each other, is there any simple fast ways to do so? i need a pretty good method as it is will be the most important part of the app.

Comment: You Should check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587208/detect-collision-of-two-uiviews-in-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect collision of two UIView's in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587208/detect-collision-of-two-uiviews-in-swift)

Comment: Yea this method is just right for me, Thanks man!