# How to see if two UIImageView's have touched

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview

How can I determine if two UIImageViews's have touched each other? I'm trying to make it realize they've touched each other and then add some code inside if they did.

Hope someone can help, thanks!

I have already tried

```
if (newArea.frame.intersects(yolo.frame)) {

        print("ok")

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect collision of two UIView's in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587208/detect-collision-of-two-uiviews-in-swift)

Comment: nah, that solution doesn't work for my problem

Comment: You need to clarify your specific needs. The code you posted checks if the frames of two views intersect. If that isn't what you want then update your question with more specific details of what you need. Maybe show an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if `UIImageViews` are overlapping like that:

```
if img1.bounds.contains(img2.bounds) 
{
   print("overlapped")
}
```

Comment: This is probably a bad answer, as bounds basically always start from `(0,0)` and this will not recognize the case when they do not intersect. The original code from question is good, under the assumption that the image views have the same `superview`. They probably don't so that's why it doesn't work

Comment: is there any difference between intersect and touch?

Comment: The question was to find if two images touch each other, and my code simply does that.

Answer (score 1):

A proper way to do this, without depending on the view hierarchy is to use `convertRect`.

```
let r1 = newArea.superview.convert(newArea.frame, to: nil)
let r2 = yolo.superview.convert(yolo.frame, to: nil) 
if r1.intersects(r2) { stuff() }
```

This converts both frames to screen coordinates and then checks the intersection, before they were local coordinates of superviews.