# How to avoid two buttons bumping into each other inside a view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, uianimation

I am developing a simple game where i need bubbles moving through out the screen as shown in the below Pic.

[image: Image Showing The Bubbles inside the View]

In the Image shown above **Bubbles 7 and 10, 4 and 9 are bumping into each other**. I need the Bubbles to move through out the screen without bumping into each other.

I am adding the bubbles inside a loop and changing the positions randomly as shown below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {

    self.bubbleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.bubbleButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 50.0, 60.0, 60.0);
    self.bubbleButton.tag = i+1;        
    [self.bubbleButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.bubbleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTapOfBubble:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.bubbleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"circle"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:self.bubbleButton];

    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void * _Nullable)(number)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    CGFloat x = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.width);
    CGFloat y = (CGFloat) (arc4random() % (int) self.view.bounds.size.height);
    CGPoint squarePostion = CGPointMake(x, y);
    self.bubbleButton.center = squarePostion;
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationLoop:finished:context:)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

I am not able to figure on how to avoid the bubbles bumping into each other. Can someone please suggest me on how to get this done?

Comment: please check this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587208/detect-collision-of-two-uiviews-in-swift) may help you.