# How to create a Collision Detection between a label and an Image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, collision

**INTRUDUCTION**

I want to create a simple game where you should be able to drag a label and if you drag it in the correct place, you win. To be more specific: This is a game to help children with autism. In this game they have to create the correct sequence of numbers from one to ten dragging the label with the number in the correct place (which is an image actually). now you will understand better: [image: CLICK HERE TO SEE THE APP (STORYBOARD]

**PROBLEM**

I have already created the code to drag the labels (with a pan gesture recognizer) but I don't know how to create a Collision detection: When the card "1" is dragged and it collides with the blue image "1" something happens, 
my mentally code is:

```
if LB_1 *collides with* IMG_1 {
  self.IMG_1?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

I hope the question it's clear.
Ah I don't use SpriteKit. I used "SingleViewApplication" as Template not "Game".

Comment: As i understand you want to detect when one rect intersects other? use CGRect's intersects method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect collision of two UIView's in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31587208/detect-collision-of-two-uiviews-in-swift)

Comment: @shota the method intersects() doesn't work properly because when I simply touch the LB_1 the backgroundColor of IMG_1 changes even if they are not touching each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `contains()`. If you use `intersects()` then it will return true as soon as the two rectangles touch. With `contains()`, it won't return true until the dragged view is fully inside the target view, which seems much more intuitive.

I just wrote a sample app that implements this and it works perfectly.

I created a simple subclass of UIView I called BoxedView that just sets a border around it's layer so you can see it.

I set up a view controller with 2 boxed views, a larger "targetView", and a smaller view that the user could drag.

The target/action for my gesture recognizer moves the dragged view's frame as the user drags, and if target view contains the dragged view, it sets a Bool highlightTargetView, which causes the box around the target view to get thicker.

The entire view controller class' code looks like this:

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
    @IBOutlet weak var targetView: BoxedView!

    var viewStartingFrame: CGRect = CGRect.zero

    var highlightTargetView: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            targetView.layer.borderWidth = highlightTargetView ? 5 : 1
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func userDraggedView(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            viewStartingFrame = gesture.view?.frame ?? CGRect.zero
        case .changed:
            let offset = gesture.translation(in: view)
            gesture.view?.frame = viewStartingFrame.offsetBy(dx: offset.x, dy: offset.y)
            highlightTargetView = targetView.frame.contains(gesture.view?.frame ?? CGRect.zero)
        case .ended:
            gesture.view?.frame = viewStartingFrame
            highlightTargetView = false
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

In order for the math to work, I use the frame property of both views, which is in the coordinate system of the parent view (The parent view is the view controller's content view in this case, but the key thing is that we compare 2 rectangles using the same coordinate system for both.) If you used the bounds property of either view your math wouldn't work because `bounds` of a view is in the local coordinate system of that view.

Here's what that program looks like when running:

[image: View dragging GIF]

For comparison, I modified the program to also show what it looks like using the `intersects()` function, and created a video of what that looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: a stupid error ahaha, I put wrong the object that has to infersect with LB_1

Answer (score 1):

You can check if their frames intersect.
`CGRect` has method [intersects](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454747-intersects).

So you're if statement should be the following:

```
if LB_1.frame.intersects(IMG_1.frame) {
  self.IMG_1?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
}
```

If that's not enough for you, you can calculate area of [intersection rect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1455346-intersection).

Comment: The `intersects()` method just indicates that the intersection of the two rects is not empty though, right? (In other words, just that the two rectangles are touching.) It might be better to check that the larger rectangle contains the smaller using the `contains()` method (although the larger target rectangles would probably need to be **significantly** bigger or it would be tricky to get the drag lined up so that it succeeds.)

Comment: the method intersects() doesn't work properly because when I simply touch the LB_1 the backgroundColor of IMG_1 changes even if they are not touching each other. I tried putting contains() instead of intersects() but it doesn't work

Comment: For contains to work you would need to ask the larger target rect if it contains the new rect that is being dragged. If it isn't working at all then you are probably not using the right coordinate system for the comparisons. (Try logging the rects you are comparing as you make comparisons.)

Comment: mm how @DuncanC?

Comment: I posted an answer containing the code from a working sample app.